# Complicated SQL densification to query reservation data

Tags: sql, sybase, normalization

Trying to query a hotel reservation database(sybase) where, instead of having one row for each night of a guest's stay, they have created one row for each reservation and then split up the nightly rate info for each individual night into columns.  What's more, the "transaction" columns only contain data if the rate changes during the reservation.  So if a guest is charged $100 every night there is no entry in the "change" columns, but it they are charged $100(1st night), $200(2nd night), $250(3rd night) you would have two changerate, changedate column entries.

You can find the data in .CSV extract here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KhvqBcx2wpVhUUNTr1kGhgSkySTeTGposU3B3CF_2q8/edit?usp=sharing

I need one row for each night of each stay with the confnum, stay night, and room rate. My question is what is the best approach here.  Is this a densification issue with a bunch of joins or can I take another approach?

Comment: Why have you put SQL server here when its sybase ? Btw, what a crazy table design. Can you pivot it and make a new table ?

Comment: Unions over each change column with the confnum as key, but that only gives me rows for each reservation with the dates when the rates change. I am missing the dates when there is no rate change.  That is why I thought it might try densification joins after using union.

Comment: My typo Borat, just fixed it.  I was not thinking pivot.  How would I add the rows with no rate change in my query?

Comment: @user2000704 - I looked at your CSV. Can you also add a sample of your data (with say 4-5 columns) to show how the rates, dates etc are entered for just one conf number, for 1-2 days  ?

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Which Sybase product are you referring to? ASE, IQ, Sqlanwhere?  Please tag the question with database product you are using to in answering.